# Asynchronous API Request to GCloud Vision API for text detection

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, ocr, google-cloud-vision

I am trying to convert my current function to get the text out of an image with the GCloud Vision API from being synchronous to be asynchronous.

What I've found is [this](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/batch#vision_async_batch_annotate_images-python) Google Documentation page. But being honest, it is very confusing to me.

Currently, the way I do this is *(this works already)*:

```
image = vision.types.Image(content=content)
response = client.text_detection(image=image)
```

and afterwards, I work with the response.

**My goal** now is to save the asynchronous response to e.g. a **gcloud bucket**, so that my function can continue on doing the next task at hand without the need to wait for a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the link you shared the prefix in the example is 'gs://your-bucket/prefix/'. If you use that as the prefix of your output, then the result of the async operation will eventually write 1 or more result files to 'gs://your-bucket/prefix/'.

Eg: you might find a file like 'gs://your-bucket/prefix/result1.json' in your gcs bucket.

You could also use a prefix for the output like 'gs://your-bucket/something/file-prefix', which includes a filename prefix and you will have output files like be written to your gcs bucket 'gs://your-bucket/something/file-prefixresult1.json'.

It doesn't specify the exact name of the output files, just that the prefix you provide will be used so good for it to be something unique in your bucket.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but my biggest problem still is that the function is not asynchronous in the way that I can call the batch annotator and terminate the function right after. I was hoping to save some computing time compared to waiting for the response.

Comment: Can you use Google Cloud Storage Triggers? https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage  Start the async batch annotate operation and terminate your function. Set up a trigger to run a function when files are created in your bucket.

Comment: thats actually what I am doing now. It is triggered by the image upload and then processes the images asynchronously. Thanks for your help and thoughts!

Comment: Oh, I see. So when you upload an image to your bucket, a trigger causes a function to call async batch annotate for that input file. Since async batch annotate writes the output to one of your buckets, what I'm suggesting is add a new trigger that runs a cloud function to process the output files.

Comment: Exactly what I am doing now :)